# Am receiving the following syntax error when trying to set up a front end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Syntax error: super() outside of class constructor (7:4)

I'm trying to build a react front end for a ethereum d-app but am currently receiving this error,

any help would be great !!

Thanks in advance.

```
class App extends Component {
 contructor(props) {

super(props);
}

const MyContract = window.web3.eth.contract 
([{var reactexampleContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"kill","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getSecret","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"youAwesome","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"fallback"}]);

this.state = {
  ContractInstance: MyContract.at ('0x77d914f8121dd1a15862e939546d969b2ddd3ee7')
}
this.querySecret = this.querySecret.bind (this);
 }

 querySecret () {
const { getSecret } = this.state.ContractInstance;

getSecret ((err, secret) => {
  if (err) console.error ('An error occured:::::', err);
  console.log ('This is our contracts secret', secret);
})
```

Comment: It's spelled `constructor`, not `contructor`.

Comment: There is a typo. `contructor` should be `constructor`

Comment: Looks like some closing brackets are missing as well.